# Excel: Find&Replace issue

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, regex, find, find-and-replace

I'm trying to find out, how to replace only those substrings (in my case it is ,_ where _ is a space), which starts at the beginning of the cell.

I suppose, the solution should be like this regex: **FIND:** `"^, "` -> **REPLACE:** `""`

So if the cell was `"This is the , cell"` -> nothing would happened. But if the cell was ", This is the cell" it would be replaced to `"This is the cell"`

Which is the simpliest way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the alternative:

```
Sub WithoutRegex()
    For Each r In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        If Left(r.Value, 2) = ", " Then
            r.Value = Mid(r.Value, 3)
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

because the pattern is both simple and easy to detect.

**EDIT#1:**

Macros are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the macro from Excel:

1. ALT-F8
2. Select the macro
3. Touch RUN

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Comment: Thank you for response. I'm very new in Excel. Could you give me an advice where to put this code?

Comment: I would put it in a *Standard module* see my **EDIT#1**